# POST request adding space in front of mysql autoincrement id

Tags: php, mysql, auto-increment

Not sure what's going on with my auto incremented id but when I try to update nothing happens

```
UPDATE `songRequests` SET `song_played` = 'Yes' WHERE `songRequests`.`song_id` = '**\r\n** 3'
```

`\r\n` only seen when escape string added, if I don't have escape string there is a space in front of the 3. not sure how its getting in there, but unable to update info with it there.

ID pulled into previous page through a form:

```
 <form class="song-delete" action="remove.php" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="song_id" value=" <?php echo $row['song_id']; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="song_remove" value="Yes">
            <button class="song-button-remove" type="submit" name="submit">Remove</button>
        </form>
```

Comment: You have a space between `value="` and `<?php echo $row['song_id']; ?>`

Comment: thank you Barmar, that fixed it

Comment: So it's not adding anything, you put it in the form.

Comment: How could you miss it? You knew the problem was a space, doesn't that mean that you should examine your code for unwanted spaces?